# OBIEE 11g installation error at 'Merging PolicyStore application stripe'

Tags: installation, obiee, oracle-fusion-middleware

I am trying to install OBIEE 11.1.1.6 on a brand new Windows 8 machine over WebLogic 10.3.6. From my past experiences of OBIEE installation issues, I prefer to install using the Software Only mode. During configuration, I am getting the following error at 'Merging PolicyStore application stripe' step.

`[2013-03-28T22:06:31.158+05:30] [as] [TRACE] [] [oracle.as.install.bi] [tid: 15] [ecid: 0000Jqkm05x5yW^5xV_AiW1HL2cF000006,0] [SRC_CLASS: oracle.as.install.bi.biconfig.BIConfigMain] [SRC_METHOD: doExecute] Copying file: C:\Oracle\Middleware\Oracle_BI1\bifoundation\admin\provisioning\bi-policystore.xml to directory: C:\Oracle\Middleware\user_projects\domains\bifoundation_domain\config\fmwconfig, overwrite: true failed.[[
oracle.bi.installhandler.util.FileSystemException: Copying file: C:\Oracle\Middleware\Oracle_BI1\bifoundation\admin\provisioning\bi-policystore.xml to directory: C:\Oracle\Middleware\user_projects\domains\bifoundation_domain\config\fmwconfig, overwrite: true failed.
    at oracle.bi.installhandler.util.FileSystemManagerImpl.copyFile(FileSystemManagerImpl.java:194)
    at oracle.as.install.bi.biconfig.standard.MergePolicyStoreTask.doExecute(MergePolicyStoreTask.java:59)
    at oracle.as.install.bi.biconfig.standard.AbstractProvisioningTask.execute(AbstractProvisioningTask.java:70)
    at oracle.as.install.bi.biconfig.standard.StandardProvisionTaskList.execute(StandardProvisionTaskList.java:61)
    at oracle.as.install.bi.biconfig.BIConfigMain.doExecute(BIConfigMain.java:113)
    at oracle.as.install.engine.modules.configuration.client.ConfigAction.execute(ConfigAction.java:371)
    at oracle.as.install.engine.modules.configuration.action.TaskPerformer.run(TaskPerformer.java:88)
    at oracle.as.install.engine.modules.configuration.action.TaskPerformer.startConfigAction(TaskPerformer.java:105)
    at oracle.as.install.engine.modules.configuration.action.ActionRequest.perform(ActionRequest.java:15)
    at oracle.as.install.engine.modules.configuration.action.RequestQueue.perform(RequestQueue.java:64)
    at oracle.as.install.engine.modules.configuration.standard.StandardConfigActionManager.start(StandardConfigActionManager.java:160)
    at oracle.as.install.engine.modules.configuration.boot.ConfigurationExtension.kickstart(ConfigurationExtension.java:81)
    at oracle.as.install.engine.modules.configuration.ConfigurationModule.run(ConfigurationModule.java:86)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Caused by: oracle.as.config.ProvisionException: File C:\Oracle\Middleware\Oracle_BI1\bifoundation\admin\provisioning\bi-policystore.xml does not exist.
    at oracle.as.config.utl.FileUtil.validateFile(FileUtil.java:155)
    at oracle.as.config.utl.FileUtil.copyFile(FileUtil.java:351)
    at oracle.bi.installhandler.util.FileSystemManagerImpl.copyFile(FileSystemManagerImpl.java:189)
    ... 13 more`

Thanks.
Vijay.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried keeping the file in the intended location but even after that, I used to get an error at a later step. After looking at the error log, I found that there was an issue in the downloaded Disk 5 zip file.

I had to rename a folder under bishiphome from 11.1.1.5 to 11.1.1.6. The installation was smooth after I renamed the folder.

I am 99.9 percent sure that I downloaded the 11.1.1.6 zip file.

Answer (score 0):

Vijay,

I saw you posting in the OTN Forum as well.

Here is a link to a copy of the "bi-policystore.xml" from the BI Sample App (a fully contained Linux instance with 11.1.1.6.2):

http://www.adrive.com/public/cBjnjn/bi-policystore.xml

You could also download the full Sample App from here:

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/middleware/bi-foundation/obiee-samples-167534.html

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the file Novadar. But even after placing the file in the desired location, it get's stuck in a couple of steps later, while restarting the admin server. I have tried to continue but it does not install properly.